# Sequel(mysql2) not reconnecting when mysql connection lost

Tags: ruby, sequel, mysql2

sequel(mysql2) not reconnecting to mysql when connection lost.

Below is the error when querying.

> 'Sequel::DatabaseDisconnectError: Mysql2::Error: closed MySQL connection'.

Comment: yes, added mysql2 gem file.

Answer (score 1):

Use Sequel's [ConnectionValidator](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc-plugins/files/lib/sequel/extensions/connection_validator_rb.html) extension to periodically validate connections and reopen connections when they're closed like this.